# Google Analytics support for PWA studio venia setup

Tags: magento2.4.5, pwa, google-analytics, venia

By default Magento provides an option to track Google Analytics by configuration.

As We are using PWA Studio Venia setup, Is there any by default support by magento for Google analytics tracking ? Or do we need to Integrate manually for all events ?

[image]